# Why does tox cause coverage failures against mypy with Python 3.10.9

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, tox

I am attempting to set up a continuous integration environment using `mypy`, `pytest`, `flake8`, `pytest-cov`, and `black`.  My directory structure for this test project titled `hello` is the following.

```
hello
|_hello
|    |___init__.py
|    |_add.py
|_tests
|    |___init__.py
|    |_test_add.py
|_pyproject.toml
```

my `pyproject.toml` file has the following content.

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Jon Webb <webbja123@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.rst"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.2.1"
flake8 = "^6.0.0"
mypy = "^1.0.1"
black = "^23.1.0"
isort = "^5.12.0"
flake8-bandit = "^4.1.1"
flake8-bugbear = "^23.2.13"
flake8-builtins = "^2.1.0"
flake8-comprehensions = "^3.10.1"
flake8-implicit-str-concat = "^0.4.0"
flake8-print = "^5.0.0"
tox = "^4.4.6"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: MacOS",
    "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
]

[tool.isort]
profile = 'black'

[tool.black]
line-length = 90
target-version = ['py38', 'py39', 'py310']
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.eggs
  | \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
  # The following are specific to Black, you probably don't want those.
  | blib2to3
  | tests/data
  | profiling
)/
'''

[tool.tox]
legacy_tox_ini = """
    [tox]
    env_list = py310, coverage, mypy, flake8

    [testenv]
    description = run tests with pytest
    deps = pytest
    commands = pytest -v {posargs}

    [testenv:coverage]
    deps = pytest-cov
    commands =
        pytest --cov --cov-report term-missing --cov-report html --cov-append --cov-context=test --cov-fail-under=100 {posargs}

    [testenv:mypy]
    deps = mypy
    commands = mypy hello

    [testenv:flake8]
    deps = flake8
    commands = flake8 hello
"""

[tool.mypy]
exclude = ["docs", "tests"]
check_untyped_defs = true
disallow_any_generics = true
disallow_incomplete_defs = true
disallow_untyped_defs = true
no_implicit_optional = true

[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = ["tests"]
console_output_style = "progress"
```

When I run tox, everything works perfectly, except for code coverage.  However, the code coverage is 100% as expected, and the problems appears to be something different than the coverage itself.  I get the following output message, which seems to indicate that the `testenv:coverage` section of my config file is mangling with the `testenv:mypy` section.  I get the following message when I run tox.

```
platform linux -- Python 3.10.9, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
cachedir: .tox/coverage/.pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/Python/hello, configfile: pyproject.toml, testpaths: tests
plugins: cov-4.0.0
collected 2 items

tests/test_add.py ..                                                     [100%]

---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.10.9-final-0 -----------
Name                Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------
conftest.py             0      0   100%
hello/__init__.py       0      0   100%
hello/add.py            4      0   100%
tests/__init__.py       0      0   100%
tests/test_add.py      12      0   100%
-------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                  16      0   100%
Coverage HTML written to dir htmlcov

Required test coverage of 100% reached. Total coverage: 100.00%

============================== 2 passed in 0.03s ===============================
coverage: commands[1]> '[testenv:mypy]'
coverage: exit 2 (0.00 seconds) /home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/Python/hello> '[testenv:mypy]'
coverage: FAIL ✖ in 1.39 seconds
mypy: install_package> python -I -m pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps /home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/Python/hello/.tox/.tmp/package/51/hello-0.1.0.tar.gz
mypy: OK ✔ in 1.17 seconds
flake8: install_package> python -I -m pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps /home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/Python/hello/.tox/.tmp/package/52/hello-0.1.0.tar.gz
flake8: commands[0]> flake8 hello
.pkg: _exit> python /home/jonwebb/Code_Dev/Python/hello/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproject_api/_backend.py True poetry.core.masonry.api
  py310: OK (1.33 seconds)
  coverage: FAIL code 2 (1.39=setup[1.20]+cmd[0.19,0.00] seconds)
  mypy: OK (1.17 seconds)
  flake8: OK (1.28=setup[1.20]+cmd[0.08] seconds)
  evaluation failed :( (5.29 seconds)
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this failure?

Comment: Could you please run `tox -rvv` and paste the whole output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, but for some reason `tox` expects the coverage command to be last.  When I re-write the command as the following, everything works fine.

```
[tool.tox]
legacy_tox_ini = """
    [tox]
    env_list = py310, coverage, mypy, flake8

    [testenv]
    description = run tests with pytest
    deps = pytest
    commands = pytest -v {posargs}

    [testenv:mypy]
    deps = mypy
    commands = mypy hello

    [testenv:flake8]
    deps = flake8
    commands = flake8 hello

[testenv:coverage]
    deps = pytest-cov
    commands =
        pytest --cov --cov-report term-missing --cov-report html --cov-append --cov-context=test --cov-fail-under=100 {posargs}
"""
```